# RadioButtons hooked up to my change() jQuery event don't fire

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, events, radio-button, onchange

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[name="paymenttype"]').change(function () {
        alert("works!"); // This doesn't fire.
    });
</script>

<div id="paymentselector">
    <label>
        <input name="paymenttype" value="deposit" type="radio" />Deposito
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="paymenttype" value="creditcard" type="radio" />Tarjeta de Credito
    </label>
</div>
```

According to the documentation, this should work:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

In the change() event, the alert isn't fired.

Is something wrong in my Javascript code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding a document ready handler -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="paymenttype"]').change(function () {
    alert("works!"); // This doesn't fire.
   });
});
```

Comment: Always forget about this event. Thank you. That fixed the issue. Obviously the event tried to wire up but the element wasn't there yet.

Answer (score 2):

Well, right off the bat, you need to wrap your JS in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` block. When the JS is run, the element it's trying to access doesn't exist yet.